# Magento: Show a products immediate categories, not parent or grand-parents and display on different lines

Tags: magento, parent, categories, product

I'm building a store that has proven a little difficult and the client has requested some things that seem like a lot of effort for not much benefit.

They want the product brand, type, name and year all on new lines on catalogue and page views.

I have reasoned that can be achieved through placing the products into brand and type categories (and unfortunately year as well which I'm working to find another solution as this will be a nightmare). These categories are in parent categories called Shop By Brand and Shop By Type.

I'm wanting to echo the immediate categories of the product individually. So echo BRAND and echo TYPE. This is so the order can be BRAND, NAME, TYPE.

To achieve this I need to get the immediate category and not grand-parent category of the product, and echo each individually.

This is unless somebody presents a more elegant solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with attributes. Let's say you add a new attribute, 'Year' (attribute code 'year'). Add that into your attribute set and enter a value.

```
//display the year
echo $_product->getYear();
```

The same method can be used for other attributes. There'a already a 'manufacturer' attribute you can use for this, or if you're a stickler for semantics, you can create a new 'brand' attribute and use the same concept (manufacturer and brand are not the same thing to some store owners).

```
//display the brand
echo $_product->getBrand();
```